# Check if value exist in OBJECT?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have some obejct thats looks like this

```
{
  "tasks": [
    {
      "name": "Task YES",
      "finished": false,
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "Task NO",
      "finished": false,
      "id": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

And some value

```
let someValue = 'Task NO';
```

How to check if there already value inside JSON?

Comment: A recursive function would be the way to go here.

Comment: That's an object with one property which contains an array of objects and not [JSON](http://json.org). Grab `tasks`, iterate over the elements and check the `name` property of the objects

Comment: Ok, i have just renamed the question, sorry

Comment: Do you want check for value inside tasks array only?

Comment: Yes, only there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to accomplish what you're looking to do is to use [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

```
let task = tasks.find(task => task.name === someValue);
```

If the task is found with the same `name` as `someValue`, `task` will be equal to the found task. If it can't find an anything, then `task` will be `undefined`.

```js
const taskList = {
  "tasks": [
    {
      "name": "Task YES",
      "finished": false,
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "Task NO",
      "finished": false,
      "id": 2
    }
  ]
};

let someValue = 'Task NO';
let task = taskList.tasks.find(task => task.name === someValue);
console.log(task);

if (task) console.log(`Task with the ID of ${task.id} already has this name`);
else console.log("No task with that name was found");
```

Comment: _"The best way..."_ totally depends on the use case and what the TO plans to do with the information that there might already be a task with a given name. The _"best way"_ could also be to use `Array.prototype.some()`, or `Array.prototype.filter()` or a simple `for` loop ...

Comment: Sorry you're right, that's totally my bad on the phrasing. I've modified my answer with better wording :)

Comment: You could instantly cast it to a boolean like this: `let task = !!tasks.find(task => task.name === someValue);`

Comment: At that point you may as well use `Array.prototype.some()`, as you suggested in your answer. I thought the OP may want to know what the ID for the found task was, which requires preserving the found element. Without knowing the context I can't know either way.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a job for [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), which tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.

```js
let obj = {
  "tasks": [
    {
      "name": "Task YES",
      "finished": false,
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "Task NO",
      "finished": false,
      "id": 2
    }
  ]
}

console.log(obj.tasks.some(i => i.name == 'Task NO'))
console.log(obj.tasks.some(i => i.name == 'Task YES'))
console.log(obj.tasks.some(i => i.name == 'Task ABC123'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following function:

```
function isValueExist(obj, value) {
  if (!(obj instanceof Object) && 'function' !== typeof obj) {
    return obj === value;
  }

  for (var prop in obj)  {
    if (isValueExist(obj[prop], value)) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`JSON.parse` reviver parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Examples) can be used to recursively enumerate, modify, or exclude values:

```js
var someValue = 'Task NO', json = '{"tasks":[{"name":"Task YES","finished":false,"id":1},{"name":"Task NO","finished":false,"id":2}]}';

var obj = JSON.parse(json, function(key, value) {
  if (value == someValue) 
    console.log(`found: '${value}' at key '${key}'`);
  return value;                                           // optional if the result obj is needed
});
```

Answer (score -1):

quite inefficient but a hacky version with [Boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) object -))

```
Boolean(d.tasks.filter(e => e.name == "Task NO"))
```

**EDIT**

saved 7 bytes -)) [thanks to @Get Off My Lawn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51349514/check-if-value-exist-in-object/51349679?noredirect=1#comment89671864_51349679)

```
!!d.tasks.filter(e => e.name == "Task NO")
```

**Another Update.**

As [@Andreas commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51349514/check-if-value-exist-in-object/51349679?noredirect=1#comment89673601_51349679), `Boolean([])` returns true. So, answer should be updated as,

```
!!d.tasks.filter(e => e.name == "Task NO").length
```

Comment: You could just do `!!d.tasks.filter(e => e.name == "Task NO")`

Comment: more sexy -)) liked it

Comment: Based on your edit, I'm assuming you frequently codegolf? :P

Comment: yes, definitely -))

Comment: Did you even test your answer? An empty array is truthy hence both your "answers" will always be `true`: `Boolean([]) === true`

Comment: thanks for suggestion. haven't checked that case before. i've fixed it.